# How do you get value from another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am starting to learn about object-oriented programming and I'm having a rough time with it.
I have some questions about it:

```py
class Record:
    """Represent a record."""
    def __init__(self, category, name, value):
        self._category = category
        self._name = name
        self._value = value
        # 1. Define the formal parameters so that a Record can be instantiated
        #    by calling Record('meal', 'breakfast', -50).
        # 2. Initialize the attributes from the parameters. The attribute
        #    names should start with an underscore (e.g. self._amount)
    @property
    def amount (self):
        return self._value
    # Define getter methods for each attribute with @property decorator.
    # Example usage:
    # >>> record = Record('meal', 'breakfast', -50)
    # >>> record.amount
    # -50

class Records:
    """Maintain a list of all the 'Record's and the initial amount of money."""
    def __init__(self):
        # 1. Read from 'records.txt' or prompt for initial amount of money.
        # 2. Initialize the attributes (self._records and self._initial_money)
        #    from the file or user input.
        self._records =[]
        self._money = 0
        fh = open(file='records.txt', mode='r')
            if ',' not in i:
                self._money = int(i.strip())
            else:
                raw_line = i.strip()
                category, activity, value = raw_line.split(',')
                x = Record(category, activity, value)
                self._records.append(x)
            print("Welcome back!")
            fh.close()
    @property
    def view(self):
        for i in self._records:
            print(Record._category)
        #1. Print all the records and report the balance.

x = Records()
Records.view()
```

I wanted to print out value from my newly acquired list but I don't know how to pass my data from class `Records` to class `Record` for processing. How should I approach this?

Comment: "I wanted to print out value from my newly acquired list" To be clear: the question is, inside the loop `for i in self._records:`, how to use the `Record` instance that is stored in the `self._records` list, and *currently named `i`* (because that is how `for` loops work)? Well, if you had an instance of the `Record` class named `i` in *any other context*, what would you do?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel because we want to save our data as objects and we need to pass the data between classes? The tutorial I have been watching is doing it in an interactive shell, so they can show the values of an instance of a class using def __repr__(self): . I don't know what should I write so I can bring the instance to the 'Record' class.

Comment: No, you don't pass your data between classes. You pass your data between *methods* - just as you pass your data between *functions* when you *aren't* (consciously) using OOP. The distinguishing feature of methods vs. functions is that they are bound to - objects, not classes. The *only* role that classes have in this is to *contain the code that describes how the object works*. You do not "bring the instance to the Record class"; classes aren't "places". Your *object is an instance of* the Record class - meaning, they are **things**, and "Record" is the **kind of thing** that they are.

Comment: Put another way: suppose I had a loop like `for i in ["one", "two", "three"]:`. Now I want to "bring" (as you put it) the values of `i` "to the `str` class", so that I can manipulate the strings. How would I do that? The question doesn't make sense as asked, right? It's a string, so you just use it the way you normally would - calling the string methods, or accessing other attributes, using `.`.